# Mysql replication trouble with event_scheduler

Tags: mysql

I'm running replication Master-Slave in MySQL 5.5. One day, my replication is broken. The `show slave status` given me 1032 error:

> Last_SQL_Error: Could not execute Update_rows event on table
>   db.banner_optimize; Can't find record in
>   'tvc_banner_kpi_optimize', Error_code: 1032; handler error
>   HA_ERR_END_OF_FILE; the event's master log mysql-bin.004055,
>   end_log_pos 20805222

I did some google, and found some solutions pointed that disable `event_scheduler` in slave can solve this error.

In slave, `event_scheduler` was disabled:

```
mysql> select @@event_scheduler;
+-------------------+
| @@event_scheduler |
+-------------------+
| DISABLED          |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I stop the slave, `set global sql_slave_skip_counter = 1`, then start slave. The Replication is running again but the delay time is very big, about 10 000 seconds and keep increasing.

For a period of time, the 1032 error still occur. Can anyone tell me what is really causes this problem?

PS: In master, `event_scheduler` is `ON`.